# Customizing tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout in my app that looks like this:

[image]

I want to make it look something like this:

[image]

I want the middle icon to be a bit bigger and half outside the tablayout container. I have my tablayout setup with a viewpager with the icons set in the following way:

```
            tabLayout.GetTabAt(0).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.homewhite);

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.messageWhite);

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(2).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.upload_icon);

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(3).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.notifWhite);

        tabLayout.GetTabAt(4).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.profWhite);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: you can accomplish this by using relative layout container, the height of it will be wrap_content(of the inlarged icon) and will align to bottom.
there will be another layout that will contain the icons from the left and right of the enlarged icon.

Comment: so the middle icons will be in a separate layout?

Comment: yes, two layouts within one relative layout

Comment: But then how can I associate it with the viewpager?

Comment: in the viewpager tag add the following layout_above="@id/your_container"
or just use vertical linearlayout with weights